# How remove header view and footer view in section from UITableView in swift ?

Tags: swift, uitableview

i ask again the question because it's not working for me despite the answers i read.

I try this but I Have still header and footer view in section :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView=nil
    tableView.tableFooterView=nil
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func headerViewForSection(section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView? {

    return nil

}

func footerViewForSection(section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView? {
    return nil

}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can set header and footer height to minimum value.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.1
}
```

So, Here footer and header won't be visible to user.